# Command line tool to convert vector GPKG to PNG

Tags: geopackage

I have around 30,000 vector .gpkg files that I'd like to convert each to a .png or .jpg file.

Is there any command line tool that does this?

I tried GDAL but it did not work:

```
$ gdal_translate insee_02532.gpkg insee_02532.png
ERROR 4: `insee_02532.gpkg' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

Edit: ogrinfo output:

```
$ ogrinfo -so -al insee_02532.gpkg
INFO: Open of `insee_02532.gpkg'
      using driver `GPKG' successful.

Layer name: insee_02532
Geometry: Multi Polygon
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (3.330713, 49.733178) - (3.371605, 49.767545)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World"],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
FID Column = fid
Geometry Column = geom
insee: String (80.0)
nom: String (80.0)
wikipedia: String (80.0)
surf_ha: Real (0.0)
```

Expected result: a simple picture of the shape, like this:

[image]

(this is a result I got out of the box after uploading one of my gpkg files on [this website](https://mygeodata.cloud/conversion#))

Note: I don't care about the background, I'm only interested in seeing the shape.

One of my .gpkg files for example: [here](https://easyupload.io/88nwf8)

Comment: `gdal_translate` is a raster oriented command, gpkg format is rather vectorial, so it is processed with `ogr...` commands; can you post the output of `ogrinfo -so -al insee_02532.gpkg` so we can help you further

Comment: @ElioDiaz Thanks, I added the ogrinfo output to the question

Comment: GeoPackage can contain both raster data and vectors but because gdal_translate gives that error your GeoPackage contains only vectors. You can rasterize vector data with gdal_rasterize.

Comment: What are you expecting to see in the PNG for that GeoPackage file (insee_02532.gpkg)?

Comment: @BradHards I updated the question with an image of what I'm expecting as an output.

Comment: Can you code in Python or R or anything? Because the way I'd do it is to use a programming language with geospatial capabilities to read the geopackage data, read some background tiles from OpenStreetMap, and then draw the map, saving as a PNG. Loop over 30,000 files. You could possibly also do it with QGIS' Atlas feature.

Comment: @Spacedman Sure, I can code in Python, but I have no idea of what package to use and what apis to look for as I'm entirely new to the GIS field. Do you have any code sample that could be close to what I need?

Comment: Searching for spatial data in python should turn up packages like `fiona`, `geopandas`, `folium`. And lots of useful guides and tutorials.

Comment: I believe @Spacedman 's answer about atlas in Qgis is the best for your purpose; but first you should merge all our gpkgs into a single one, that's easily done with `ogrmerge.py` at the command line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution worked for me:

```
$ ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" shp/ gpkg/insee_12345.gpkg
$ gdal_rasterize -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -ot Byte -ts 1000 1000 -l insee_12345 shp/insee_12345.shp tiff/insee_12345.tiff
$ convert tiff/insee_12345.tiff jpg/insee_12345.jpg
```

So that's gpkg → shp → tiff → jpg. (I couldn't find a shorter way.)

(caveat: it does not properly preserve proportions (the width/height ratio) as the shape is spread to be always 1000px in width and height), but for my use case, the output is close enough to what I want)